# Can I rotate car using location in Google map?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I got this data from the socket and I need to change the rotation of
car base on changed location. how can I rotate(left, right, top,
bottom) car?

```
{
    carType = Sedan;
    latitude = "41.738751";
    longitude = "-88.274285";
}
```

I also try this but doesn't work:

```
float dy = newLocation.latitude - oldLocation.latitude;
float dx = cosf(M_PI/180*oldLocation.latitude)*(newLocation.longitude - oldLocation.longitude);
float angle = atan2f(dy, dx);
driverMarker.rotation = angle;
```

[image]

Comment: you should use bearing

Comment: is these cars on the maps is map markers?

Comment: YES. it's map markers.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the rotation like:

```
marker.rotation = angle value
```

Comment: i know this but all time i got "angle" value 0.

Comment: So your question is wrong you should ask how to get or calculate angle...Check you asked how can i rotate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the angle for rotating the car marker:

```
func angleBetween(oldLocation: CLLocation, newLocation: CLLocation) -> Double {
    let originLocation = CLLocation(latitude: newLocation.coordinate.latitude - oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: newLocation.coordinate.longitude - oldLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let bearingRadians = atan2(originLocation.coordinate.latitude, originLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let bearingDegrees = bearingRadians * 180 / Double.pi
    return bearingDegrees 
}
```

And you can use it like this

```
let angle = angleBetween(oldLocation: oldLocation, newLocation: newLocation)
```

And you can use `marker.rotation` like @Daljeet said:

```
marker.rotation = angle
```

Comment: You can also use Float.pi instead of Float(Double.pi)

Answer (score 0):

Use Core Location delegate method.
It will give the direction of your phone.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) 
{

        let direction = newHeading.trueHeading as Double
        print("Direction :- \(direction)");
        currentLoaction.rotation = direction
}
```

Set those direction for your location marker.
here: **currentLoaction** is

**var currentLoaction:GMSMarker = GMSMarker()**

Hope this will help you if you used Google Map.